# Can private key .pem file work for Azure VM with dynamic changing IP?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I created VM on Azure cloud and downloaded private key .pem file. With this I successfully managed to ssh from MobaXTerm to VM running on cloud.

then as my work finished, i stopped the VM however did not retain the IP.

next day when i would start my VM, understandably vm was assigned a new IP. Now i am trying to connect to VM from my MobaXterm using the same .pem file - I am unable to connect.

My question here is - According to functionality Can i connect to this new IP with existing pem file ? is it allowed ? or i am facing some other technical problem on my side that's why connection is not happening !

thank you
ashish parab

Comment: How do you use the .pem file when ssh to the VM?

Comment: inside advanced ssh setting of MobaXTerm , there will be a checkbox saying use private key. tick that check box and browse the respective .pem file

Comment: Where do you download the .pem file?

Comment: when you create a vm on azure for the first time, it lets you download the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to functionality Can I connect to this new IP with existing
> .pem file ? is it allowed?

It's not the problem of the .pem file. The private key works forever and won't change if you do not change it, even if the public IP of the VM change.

The possible problem as I think is that your firewall blocks the SSH traffic. Check the NSG rules associated with your VM for the SSH port 22. And the firewall rules in your local network and your machine also need to be checked.

Comment: yeah...there might be a connection issue on that day. i recreated the same scenario today and it is working. same .pem file , I am able to connect to new IP.